editing google sheets import option
I need to access downloaded csv files via "File - import" in a google sheet in order to edit the file (write apps script) to automate imports from that file into a specific google sheet as that file receives new data from manually downloaded csv files. I have no script to show here because I cannot link to the file of downloaded csv files. The downloaded files come from my SquareSpace Website and cannot be automatically downloaded. I must manually download one file at a time then manually import one file at a time to the specified google sheet which is what I want to automate.
I have tried numerous queries from google help, stackoverflow , etc. however no answers specifically address my question. Can someone tell me how this can be done. Thank you.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Automate imports from downloaded CSV files
This is the script that I've provided and it's working on my end.

I saved the CSV file in to my gdrive folder.
I get the folder id and save it to the variable.
I parse the csv file into a sheet using a loop.


function importCSVFiles() {
  const folderId = 'Your folders ID';
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

  const files = folder.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());

    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

  }
}

  

Sample Output

Sample Sheet

References:
Class DriveApp
parseCsv

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain how this answers the question.

I already added an explanation on top.
